# Can we please nuke the "Welcome Back" banner?

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

I've got accounts on a lot of sites across the network. Some I use daily, others are more ad-hoc.

Every time I visit a site I haven't seen in a while, I get

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful,
>
> don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.

It's okay. You can relax, I haven't forgotten how the sites work, and I *really* don't need you to keep telling me for no reason.

I'm not sure of the original rationale, so there may be a good reason for it. If so, tracking visit date across the network would cut down the noise to near-zero.

Alternatively, perhaps anyone with a rep > 1k on *any* site gets a pass?

Comment: Fwiw, the criteria for showing this require that you haven't been on the site for at least 72 hours... That may have stopped working. What site did you see this on, and roughly what time did you see it?

Comment: @Shog9 It was one of the hot topics links presented to me about 2 minutes before this question was posted [Most likely the top one]. Apolofies for not being more precise, I browsed more while formatting and don't recall the order.

Comment: @Shog9 Not sure if you found the notification in question, but I'd argue that having had an account for the best part of 10 years, I'm not going to forget how to vote over the course of three days. [At least, not without having far larger issues to deal with]

Comment: @shog9 And it's still happening... Today I opened a link to Information Security. I've got > 1,000 reputation and have had the account for over 7 years, but you still feel compelled to tell me how to vote. *Please* stop re-telling me how to use the site! It's not rocket science and I'm not an infant.